# How to build x86 and ARM in a single apk under Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In my setup, I have a simple Xamarin app `MyApp` under Visual Studio 2015. The wizard automatically generates various sub-projects such as `MyApp.Droid, MyApp.iOS`, etc. I also have a C++ Android Shared Dynamic Library project `MyShared` in the solution and `MyApp.Droid` has a reference to `MyShared`project. Here is the relevant information from `MyApp.Droid.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyShared\MyShared.vcxproj">
    <Project>{4301be08-ecf3-4c36-a487-473858bc5506}</Project>
    <Name>MyShared</Name>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>Android</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  </ProjectReference>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\MyApp\MyApp.csproj">
    <Project>{321FA0D9-3F50-4AC3-8F86-4E97DCA3FA86}</Project>
    <Name>MyApp</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Project `MyApp.Droid` also has armeabi-v7a and x86 platforms selected under Properties-->Android Options-->Advanced settings.

When I build the solution and export the apk file, here is what I see under lib/ directory:

```
lib/x86/libMyShared.so
lib/x86/libmonodroid.so
lib/x86/libmonosgen-2.0.so

lib/armeabi-v7a/libmonodroid.so
lib/armeabi-v7a/libmonosgen-2.0.so
```

As you can see, `libMyShared.so` is missing for armeabi-v7a architecture.

How do I configure the project such that libMyShared.so is built and pulled in for both the architectures? Regards.

Comment: Add each of your different `libMyShared.so` ABIs as a `EmbeddedNativeLibrary` with different `<Abi>` elements: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/ i.e. Multiple `ItemGroup`s

Comment: Thank you for your help. The link says that nothing special needs to be done under Visual Studio 2015 other than adding a reference (which I have done).

Comment: Can you post both of the `ItemGroup`s in your `.csproj` for the `libMyShared.so` native reference

Comment: I have updated the main post. Note that, according to Xamarin documentation, I need to define a project reference to MyShared (and not EmbeddedNativeLibrary). Using project reference sets up proper build dependency order.

Comment: The native references would be in your Android Library project if that is where you are adding them and creating the C# bindings, post the `ItemGroup`s from that one.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I believe you are thinking about C# Android Library project (which I don't have). I have a C++ Android Library project. When this project is built, it will create an .so file. By default, Xamarin is building only one .so file. I need the .so files to be built for both the architectures.

Comment: The Xamarin add-in is not "building" the C++ library(ies), you will want to set the `AndroidArch` in your VS Android-C++ project and have msbuild compile the project for each ABI needed. You can assign a property group variable to that element and change it for each build required. Then you can add multiple ABI references to those shared libraries in your Xamarin-Based project.