# Can't compile and include armeabi native library

Tags: c++, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a native library (.so) for armeabi architecture, but I can't find the way.

I have achieved to compile and run successfully my native library for armeabi-v7a. It seems like Visual C++ 2017 (15.5.5) compiles for this architecture by default.

The closest question I found to my problem is this one: [How to build x86 and ARM in a single apk under Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456262/how-to-build-x86-and-arm-in-a-single-apk-under-xamarin)

In its [last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456262/how-to-build-x86-and-arm-in-a-single-apk-under-xamarin#comment66238083_39456262), the user "SushiHangover" mentions the AndroidArch property, but I can't figure out how to use it.

In this [other link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) I have found that the GCC compiler defaults to armeabi (I have been using clang). I've tried it, but the .so still goes to armeabi-v7a folder inside the APK (and it runs correctly)

Does anyone knows how to compile armeabi native libraries with Visual C++ and create a fat APK (with the .so library compiled for all the architectures)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which tools were you using to compile the .so file? Android Studio?

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2017 15.5.5. I have created the project using "New Project -> Visual C++ -> Cross Platform -> Android -> Dynamic Library (Android)", and then referenced with "Add Reference..." from my Xamarin.Android project.